# calculator output in c

Tags: c, output, calculator

I made a simple calculator program using switch case, but the output is different than I expected.

```
int main(){

    double a, b;
    double sum = 0;
    char o; //operator

    printf("Enter operator\n");
    scanf("%c", &o);
    printf("Enter first operand\n");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("Enter second operand\n");
    scanf("%f", &b);



    switch (o)
    {

        case '+':
            sum = a + b;
            break;

        case '-':
            sum = a - b;
            break;
        case '*':
            sum = a * b;
            break;
        case '/':
            sum = a / b;
            break;
            if (b == 0){ printf("Error"); }
            break;

    }


    printf("The result is\n%10.10lf\n", sum);



    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

The result of 'sum' is some huge astronomical numbers. Can someone tell why?

Comment: While we are at it: it's almost always a bad idea to compare floating point numbers to a constant (`if (b == 0)...`). Floating point representation is never accurate, you should always compare to a small range (`if (fabs(b) < EPSILON)...`) where `EPSILON` is a small number representing your intended precision. Also note that with floating point IEEE representation, you have a +0.00 and a -0.00 (which are different numbers). Your test will only catch the first case.

Comment: @mfro sometimes equality testing is fine. Seems ok here. As for -0, you got that wrong. `-0.0 == 0.0`

Comment: @David Heffernan: I probably wasn't precise enough in what I wanted to say: the comparision in the original code was meant to avoid `INF` as result. This doesn't work for small numbers (division still results in INF), thus you must compare to `something + EPSILON`. `-0.0 == +0.0` is correct, but `-0.0 + EPSILON` is different to `+0.0 + EPSILON`, thus `fabs()` is needed.

Comment: @mfro that's not true either. `-0.0 + x == 0.0 + x` for all `x`. The way to handle divide by zero is to do the divide and then check for INF. Trying to predict the INF is difficult. Your code will fail to do so accurately.

Answer (score 3):

`a` and `b` are both of type `double`. The correct format specifier for `double` in `scanf` is `%lf`, not `%f` (which is for `float`).

```
scanf("%lf", &a);
```

Note that in `printf`, `%f` is used or for `double` (the same for `float` because it's promoted to `double`). Since C99, `%lf` in `printf` is the same as `%f`.

Comment: It works, thanks! I now have the problem of division by zero. Instead of printing the error message, it shows a weird result of 1.INF or something

Comment: @user2309261 For that problem, move the part to test if `b == 0` before calculating `sum = a / b;`

Comment: Rather remove `break` in the middle.

Comment: @keltar It's better to not perform the division, if the goal is to detect that division by zero is about to happen.

Comment: @unwind with current breaks it will not prevent division. But anyway, what benefits it gives if arguments are floats?

Comment: I believe that `%lf` has been allowed in printf since C99.

Comment: @YuHao err.. how can it accept both double and long double for the same `%lf`, if their size is different, and double isn't being promoted to long double? I believe it is `%Lf` for long double, `%lf` for double and `%f` for float (but float => double via implicit rules).

Comment: @keltar You are right, I have false memory for this issue, fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

Try `%lf` instead of `%f` because that way you will have `a` and `b` as the type `double` rather than `float`.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to convert `double` to `float` which is not **implicitly** possible inside `scanf` or `printf` function. What `scanf` was doing, It was purging/reformatting the whole (double)input into an empty float value. Here is working one :

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(){

    double a, b;
    double sum = 0;
    char o; //operator

        printf("Enter operator\n");
        scanf("%c", &o);
        printf("Enter first operand\n");
        scanf("%lf", &a);
        printf("Enter second operand\n");
        scanf("%lf", &b);

        switch (o)
        {

        case '+':
            sum = a + b;
            break;

        case '-':
            sum = a - b;
            break;
        case '*':
            sum = a * b;
            break;
        case '/':
            sum = a / b;
            break;
            if (b == 0){ printf("Error"); }
            break;
        }

        printf("The result is\n %f\n", sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As everyone has pointed out, you need `scanf ("%lf", &a);` and same for b.
Now in your switch statement you wanted to prevent division by zero :

```
case '/':
    sum = a / b;
    break;
    if (b == 0){ printf("Error"); }
    break;
```

But what happens there is that you `break;` before getting to the condition. Suppose we removed that first break; the division by zero is still performed before you print the error message anyway. 
One way to prevent division by zero would be :

```
case '/':
    if (b)
        sum = a / b;
    else
        printf("Error");
    break;
```

where we check that `b != 0` before we make the division and then we either divide or print the error message.